# Dojo inheritence classes giving error while loading on construtor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, dojo, amd

I am trying to have a commonBase object which will be extended by many classes. but during loading itself, i am have a problem with construtor while my page is loaded.

My commonBase.js is

```
define(
                ["dojo/_base/declare","dojox/gfx",
                 "dojox/gfx/shape","dojo/_base/lang"
                 ], function(declare, gfx, shape, lang){
                        var commonBase = declare([], {
                                className:"commonbase",
                                x:0,
                                y:0,
                                constructor : function() {
                                        console.log("Created commonBase obj.");
                                 },
                             //some more methods.

                        });
                });
```

and my inherited class is 
shelf.js

```
define([
        "dojo/_base/declare","dojo/_base/lang",
         "view/commonBase"
        ],

        function(declare, lang, commonBase){
        //var shelf =
        return declare("view.shelf",[commonBase], {
                //className:"shelf",

                constructor: function(){
                        //declare.safeMixin(this,args);
                        console.log("shelf");
                        this.className = "shelf";
                }
        });
});
```

i am getting 
Uncaught Error: declare view.shelf: mixin #0 is not a callable constructor. dojo.js:6917

i even tried to call this.inherited() and declare.safeMixin(). but in vain.

This error is occuring during the load of the page. i understand that this is not even trying to access this object. I see in the console stack trace,it happens during some guardCheckComplete phase in dojo loader.

Comment: Can you show us commonBase?

Comment: my first code snippet is commonBase

Comment: Sorry.. my issue is solved. return was not there in my commonBase definiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `commonBase` after you define it with `declare`. The return value of the callback in `commonBase.js` is what is returned in callbacks that `require` or `define` `commonBase`.

```
var commonBase = declare([], {
    className:"commonbase",
    x:0,
    y:0,
    constructor : function() {
        console.log("Created commonBase obj.");
    },
    //some more methods.
});

return commonBase;
```